# Changing the default Node label when viewing a graph from Browser

Tags: neo4j

When you add a Node to Neo4j and you access your graph via the Neo4j Browser, the Node that was created is displayed (as a circle) and the Name property is outputted as the primary property for the Node. You can tell which Nodes are which by the name field, without having to click on them. If you do not specify a Name property, the node is just a blank circle.

I'm wondering if there is a way to specify the default "label" when visually viewing a graph via the Browser, so that I don't have to use the "name" property in order to know which Nodes are which?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This is quite simple to achieve.

- At the top you see the Label of the node (Type of node), for example
  :User.
- At the bottom of that panel, you should be able to see the    Label
  (User) along with color and size options.
- At the right corner    there should be an arrow "**<**"
- Click this to expand your options
- There should be an option to select the caption, which is the
  property you want to display by default instead of name.

Comment: It took me a moment to figure out  where to select, but I now see how to do it. You have to run a query and then select a node type from the result set at the top left where it outputs the number of nodes in a query. Once you do that, Neo4j provides formatting options for that node type. Thank you.

Comment: Thats really cool. Is there any special type you can choose that authomatcailly show the right thing or is it always the 'Type'

Answer (score 11):

Check my attached image for any doubt on where to change label.

1. Click on "Customers(1)" bubble near the top-left
2. Find the "Caption:" section near the bottom of the results area
3. Click the caption bubble desired for your label

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This is actually the correct answer for the latest neo4j browser. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

version: Neo4j 4.1.2

SELECT OBJECT
In you browser, after a request, go to the top left corner, just below the query bar. There, the names of displayed objects should appear. Select the object whose label you want to display.

DEFINE CAPTION FOR THE SELECTED OBJECT
As soon as you have selected your object, at the bottom of your browser a new menu appears. You may have to expand that menu by clicking the little triangle on the far right. In that menu, you can define the [CAPTION] (ie. the label to display on the node), its [COLOR] and [SIZE]... Just click with your mouse.