# How to make Property as First property ( which is shown on node in Neo4j Browser)

Tags: neo4j, cypher, visualization, neo4j-browser

I create a node with this cypher

```
MERGE (item:ITEM{code:'1629', price: 135000, url:'http://xuongmaythienphuc.vn/component/products/set-bo-dui-den-rot-vai-phoi-vien-logo-theu-sanh-dieu.html' })
```

On Neo4j Browser, price Property is first property and shown in the node in Visualization.

[image: viz]
[image: table]

But I want to shown Code on visualization instead (1629 instead of 135000 for the example cypher).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the default Node label when viewing a graph from Browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37495220/changing-the-default-node-label-when-viewing-a-graph-from-browser)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. click on the label above the viz
2. select the appropriate property below the viz as caption