# Changing the default Node label when viewing a graph from Browser - part 2

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-browser

I tried following @LiveWithPassion's question and @Anomaly211's answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37496695/7027147

As shown in screenshot below, my neo4j browser doesn't show me the caption as  as you can see in this image below:
[image]

Neither can I change the caption from  to any other variable as seen here.[image]

What do you think is wrong? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Check this screenshot:
Click on the Label in the red selection and select the caption property from below(Blue selection).

[image]

Comment: Don't get an option of caption when I click say 'User' in your case. I only get caption option, when I click '*' and I can't change there as well. I'm using 3.5.1 Enterprise edition.